# Common method for DRF model Viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have multiple model viewsets that overrides perform_create as below.

```
  def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user=self.request.user
        instance = serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

I am inserting this codes for every modelviewsets I am creating.  Is there any way to make this more structured instead of inserting codes everytime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should do a Mixin

```py
UserBoundModelMixin:

    user_field = "user"

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        instance = serializer.save(**{self.get_userfield(): self.request.user})
    
    def get_user_field(self):
        return self.user_field
```

```py
MyViewSet(UserBoundModelMixin, ModelViewSet):
    ...
```

Comment: Can i just let UserBoundModelMixin inherit from modelviewset?

Comment: It would not be a mixin but a base class